# Flutter assign text onchange value to variable

Tags: android, flutter

I'm following a flutter tutorial and came across a problem. It is supposed to take a value from textfield onChanged function and assign it to a variable. However it is not working. Since it is shown on iphone, I thought perhaps it works a little different on android.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String newTaskTitle;
    return Container(
       color: Color(0xff757575),
       ....

TextField(
  autofocus: true,
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  onChanged: (newText) {
     newTaskTitle = newText;
  },
),
FlatButton(
   child: Text(
       'Add',
       style: TextStyle(
           color: Colors.white,
           ),
        ),
        color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        onPressed: () {
           print(newTaskTitle);
        },
```

Comment: It turns out to be an android related issue and changing to stateful widget fixed it. Thing is that when the keyboard covers the button then after input, the textfield is reset and I keep getting null. Thank you all for quick response!

Answer (score 3):

Kalev, try using `StatefulWidget` and refreshing state when you want the new text as shown below,

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String text = 'Original text';
  String newTaskTitle;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(text),
            TextField(
              autofocus: true,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              onChanged: (newText) {
                newTaskTitle = newText;
              },
            ),
            FlatButton(
                child: Text(
                  'Add',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    text = newTaskTitle;
                  });
                }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

[image: demo]

**OR** 
You could just add **setState((){})** directly inside  **onChanged** like this

```
onChanged: (newText) {
    newTaskTitle = newText;
    setState((){});
  },
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm trying to understand why is it working in the tutorial on iphone and not on android emulator.

Comment: Not sure which tutorial you're following but you'll need to set the state to access the new state of variable.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, one of the most common issues in Flutter.

First off, are you using a `StatefulWidget`? Stateful Widgets are great for state management. They can hold a state and by using a function called `setState()`, you can change the state.

*What does `setState` do?*

The `setState()` function rebuilds the widget aka calling the `build` method again.

I would recommend storing your `newTaskTitle` variable *outside* the `build` method as it should not contain logic but also because every time `build` gets called, it will reset that variable's value.

Now, remember that `setState` function? You should use it in the `onChanged` callback like this!

```
TextField(
  autofocus: true,
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  onChanged: (newText) {
     setState(() {
       newTaskTitle = newText;
     });
  },
),
```

Now when a user types in the TextField, it will update the value. But hold on, we're not done yet. I do not recommend using the `onChanged` method to store the current value of the field. I would recommend that you use a `TextEditingController` and assign it to the `controller` property of `TextField`. You can access the text using the `TextEditingController.text` value. If you don't want to use that, at least use the callback `onEditingComplete` which will only run after the user has finished editing the field therefore not calling `setState` every time the field changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
 static String newTaskTitle;
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
    return Container(
       color: Color(0xff757575),
       ....
```

hope this works